# Magento 2.1.7 - Categories wont work - Appends "cat" tag to end of `URL`

Tags: product, category, product-attribute, catalog, catalogsearch

I'm having an issue categorizing past one level. 
An example would be if I clicked

> `category1 (100 products) --> subcategory2 (50 products) --> subcategory 3 (25 products)`,

it will only categorize and show the `50 products` of `subcategory2`.

I've found the issue is that Magento is adding the **"cat=###"** `tag` at the end of the `URL` rather than replacing the existing cat tag.

So when I try to narrow a category down past one sublevel, instead of setting the URL like this: `https://example.shop/en/products.html?cat=125`(how it should)

Magento does this: `https://example.shop/en/products.html?cat=146%2C125` (this does not work).

How would I change the way **Magento 2.1.7** narrows down `categories`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the result you are after. should he show the 50 + 25 so 75 product?

Comment: I want Magento to just show the 25 products if a user narrows down the categories to subcategory 3